# How to specify a directory for newly created text file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, settings

I'm running an old program that creates a text file and writes some data to it, despite that I haven't changed any of the settings (Solution, Project), the files are created on a directory that has nothing to do with the current project working directory.

How to specify the directory of the newly created files to be the same as the one holding the source code?

Note: Currently: Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Working Directory, is set to: `$(ProjectDir)`.

Comment: If you are using cmake to build your project, you can use cmake variables such as `PROJECT_DIR` inside your source code, which gets reconfigured to the actual directory name by cmake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could you use windows api.

```
 #include <windows.h>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
   char buff[MAX_PATH];
   string path;

   GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, buff);
   path = string(buff) + "\\file_name";

   cout << path << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Here is the msdn article on changing current directories: [**Changing the Current Directory**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363806(v=vs.85).aspx)